# Bootstrap btn-group dropdown click dropdown-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to click the dropdown item inside the `btn-group` and run alert.

This is my HTML:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 0px;border: none;">
            <i class="flaticon-more-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop2">
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Print Preview</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" id="link-report">Reports</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

For my jQuery

```
$('#table_test').on('click','.dropdown-item', function() {
    alert();
});
```

But this code is not working, can you tell me what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: are you sure your table id is 'table_test' ?

Comment: yes, im using https://keenthemes.com/metronic/ as my template

Comment: Your code works fine - assuming you really have a containing element (eg `table`) with id `table_test` .  [Here's a working JSFiddle with your exact code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/khxrtbdg/).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this is working

```js
$('#table_test tr > td').on('click','.dropdown-item', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_test">
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 0px;border: none;">
            <i class="flaticon-more-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop2">
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Print Preview</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" id="link-report">Reports</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 0px;border: none;">
            <i class="flaticon-more-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop2">
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Print Preview 2</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item" id="link-report">Reports 2</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

for me

Comment: Why do you think making OP's `$('#table_test')` selector even *more* restrictive will solve anything?  *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in your JavaScript Code. You need to call the jQuery in the `$(document).ready()` as the table id is not yet available in the DOM. Here is a complete sample code for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dropdown Menu Item Click Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#table_test").on("click", ".dropdown-item", function(){
                alert("The dropdown menu item was clicked.");
            });
        });  
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <table id="table_test" class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button id="btnGroupVerticalDrop2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding: 0px;border: none;">
                            <i>Dropdown</i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupVerticalDrop2">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Print Preview</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" id="link-report">Reports</li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>



    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can directly use this in your HTML file for simplicity. I have verified this in the W3Schools.com TryIt Editor and it's working fine for me.

As you can see above, I have put the jQuery script in the `<head>` section and I am calling the `.on("click")` function in the `$(document).ready()`. This will ensure that the table with id `table_test` is available in the DOM and then the `.on` event will be bound to the element.

Let me know if this answer works for you.

Regards,
Aj

Comment: sorry i just shorten my code, i have $(document).ready(); i think @jishan siddique 's answer is more related.. Thank you for the help anyways, this may help others.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad you found what you were looking for.